# UdpClient C# Client wont receive data from server

Tags: c#

I have a question with my `UDP` client server app. 
I have a connection between the two. They both send data to each other. Only the server receives data from the client but not the other way around but the server is sending. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace PewPewGame
{
class Client
{
    UdpClient udpClient;
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint;
    String serverIp;
    String[] dataAray;

    GameScreen gameScreen;
    Player otherPlayer;

    public Client(string serverIp, GameScreen gameScreen, Player otherPlayer)
    {
        this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
        this.otherPlayer = otherPlayer;
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        this.serverIp = serverIp;

    }
    public void clientThread()
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient(serverIp,1002);
        while (true)
        {
            RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverIp), 1002);
            receiveData();
        }
    }

    public void receiveData()
    {
        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);


            String clientData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            dataAray = clientData.Split(',');
            otherPlayer.x = Convert.ToInt32(dataAray[0]);
            otherPlayer.y = Convert.ToInt32(dataAray[1]);
            if (dataAray[3] == "1")
            {
                gameScreen.otherProjectile = new Projectile(Convert.ToInt16(dataAray[0]), Convert.ToInt16(dataAray[1]), 2, 4, 8, 8, dataAray[2]);
            }


    }

    public void sendData(string data)
    {
        Byte[] senddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        udpClient.Send(senddata, senddata.Length);
    }

    public static IPEndPoint CreateIPEndPoint(string endPoint)
    {
        string[] ep = endPoint.Split(':');
        if (ep.Length < 2) throw new FormatException("Invalid endpoint format");
        IPAddress ip;
        if (ep.Length > 2)
        {
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(string.Join(":", ep, 0, ep.Length - 1), out ip))
            {
                throw new FormatException("Invalid ip-adress");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ep[0], out ip))
            {
                throw new FormatException("Invalid ip-adress");
            }
        }
        int port;
        if (!int.TryParse(ep[ep.Length - 1], NumberStyles.None, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out port))
        {
            throw new FormatException("Invalid port");
        }
        return new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    }
}
}


using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PewPewGame
{
class Server
{
    UdpClient udpClient;
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint;

    String[] dataAray;

    GameScreen gameScreen;
    Player otherPlayer;

    public Server(GameScreen gameScreen, Player otherPlayer)
    {
        this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
        this.otherPlayer = otherPlayer;
    }

    public void serverThread()
    {
        udpClient  = new UdpClient(1002);
        while (true)
        {
            RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            receiveData();
        }
    }

    public void sendData(string data)
    {
        Byte[] senddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        udpClient.Send(senddata, senddata.Length);
    }

    public void receiveData()
    {
        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

        try
        {
            String clientData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            dataAray = clientData.Split(',');
            otherPlayer.x = Convert.ToInt32(dataAray[0]);
            otherPlayer.y = Convert.ToInt32(dataAray[1]);
            if (dataAray[3] == "1")
            {
                gameScreen.otherProjectile = new Projectile(Convert.ToInt16(dataAray[0]), Convert.ToInt16(dataAray[1]), 2, 4, 8, 8, dataAray[2]);
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: UDP knows no 'connection', so your first line is confusing.

Then you're using the `UdpClient.Send(byte[], int)` method to send data, but that expects a previous (confusingly named) call to `Connect(string, int)` or using the UdpClient constructor you're using for the client: `new UdpClient(string, int)`.

I'm pretty sure your empty catch block (do not do this, and especially do not do this if something doesn't work as expected!) catches and swallows a SocketException per the remarks from [1]:

> This overload sends datagrams to the remote host established in the Connect method and returns the number of bytes sent. If you do not call Connect before calling this overload, the Send method will throw a SocketException. If you receive a SocketException, use SocketException.ErrorCode to obtain the specific error code. Once you have obtained this code, you can refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in MSDN for a detailed description of the error.
>
> If you want to send datagrams to a different remote host, you must call the Connect method and specify the desired remote host. Use either of the other Send method overloads to send datagrams to a broadcast address.

So, in your server code:

1) Remove the empty catch block!

2) Use [another `udpClient.Send(byte[], int, IPEndPoint)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82dxxas0(v=vs.110).aspx)  that accepts the endpoint of the client - you get that via the reference you passed into `Receive(ref IPEndPoint)`

1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: try{something} catch(){//DoNothing}: the perfect paradigm of "carpet pattern" (™), (if there is some problem, put it under the carpet and ignore it!)